# Updateable progressbar on top of button

Tags: java, android

Hi i searched this like everywhere but couldnt get a real answer. How do i display i progressbar(tiny) on top of a button or an imagebutton that can be updated. Its for a music app im creating where there are lots of buttons on it like a beat box and each button plays a different music from the sound pool but i want the button to display the progressbar on it when i hit the button and the music starts. And the progress updates according to the music. i tried this in xml but cant figure it, I tried extending the view class but i dont know how to draw the progressbar on a bitmap(i tried bitmap). How can i do this? Thanks for any help. And sorry i know my english is bad.

Comment: Since there isn't something like this already provided you'll need to create your own Custom View. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: You could try setting the progress bar to clickable, and set the background of the progress bar to the android.R.btn_default.